# Using filter the data before plotting will cause missing argument

Tags: r

I want to create a shiny dashborad about some data, however, when I plotted the filtered data frame, it will cause an about 0.5s error and will show it in console.

I tried to delete the filter command which is subset(`.[,input$groupby] %in% input$selectline` and all the errors will be solved.But However, I need to filter the data to make shiny interactive.

```r
newData = mydata %>%
        group_by(`Year.ending.December`,.dots=input$groupby) %>%
        summarise(`Incidents.Recorded` = sum(`Incidents.Recorded`)/1000) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        subset(.[,input$groupby] %in% input$selectline) #This command causes the error

ggplot(newData,aes_string("Year.ending.December","Incidents.Recorded",color = input$groupby)) +
        geom_line() +
        labs(x="Year",y="Counts(thound)")
```

As the code shows above, the input$groupby will return a column name from ui.R
,however, there are multiple lines will be shown in line chart so I also need to let user select which line they want to see, therefore, `input$selectline` will return a list about data value.

Also I think my logic is ok because it will finally show the correct result, only the problem is before showing the result, there is an about 0.5s error message will be shown in the plot area as below:
Warning: Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector

```
  108: order

  105: to_basic.GeomLine

  103: layers2traces

  102: gg2list

  101: ggplotly.ggplot

   98: plotly_build.gg

   96: "plotly":::"prepareWidget"

   95: func

   82: origRenderFunc

   81: output$plotArea

    1: runApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are running that code inside a `renderPlot()` function. you can try to chage a few things: use `group_by_` instead `group_by` since `input$groupby` is a character vector. And using `filter_at` and not `subset`.

```
newData <-  mydata %>%
  group_by_("Year.ending.December", input$groupby) %>%
  summarise(`Incidents.Recorded` = sum(`Incidents.Recorded`)/1000) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter_at(vars(input$groupby), any_vars(. %in% imput$selectline))
```

If you can show a reproducible example of your app and data, with only the elements that are involved in the issue, it would be a better way to help you and test the code before any recomendation.

Comment: I followed your suggestions but the problem is still exsit. My codes have posted on github.https://github.com/YibeiNiu/YibeiNiu/tree/master/test

Comment: Make sure you're loading the `tidyverse` package

Comment: I solved this problem, I use if(nrow(newData)>0) to make sure the data frame is not empty when I using ggplot command.